# Stronger and weaker statements

Tags: soft-question

I have often seen expressions like "this statement is stronger (or weaker) than that". I know what it means. If $A\Rightarrow B$ but $B\nRightarrow A$, then $A$ is stronger than $B$.

But from time to time I read sentences like, say, "Picard's theorem is stronger than Liouville's theorem". But *both theorems are true*, so they are logically equivalent. Yeah, Picard's theorem is much harder to prove and it implies Liouville's easily. But I find one just as strong as the other.

**My question**: is there a serious definition of the terms 'strong' and 'weak' in maths, or are they just a way to speak?

Answer (score 1):

Picard's theorem and Liouville's theorem are equivalent in the sense that they have the same truth value, which is all that we require for two statements to be equivalent.

There is a subtle difference in what we mean when we say "the theorem A is stronger than the theorem B," and "the statement A is stronger than B."

You might object that these are the same, but this is a matter of terminology, and the word "strong" is used differently depending on the context.

"the theorem A is stronger than the theorem B" means "A has a better/more powerful conclusion and/or less stringent hypotheses."

"the statement A is stronger than B" means what you've said in your post: A implies B, but B does not imply A.

Answer (score 0):

In this context, it means that the second statement follows easily from the first one, but the first one is not a consequence of the second one.

Comment: But *it is* a consequence. Not easy, not obvious. But if $A$ and $B$ are true, then $A\to B$ and $B\to A$.

Comment: You are thinking in terms of Logic. That is not appropriate in this context. I was explaining what “stronger than” means in the context that you mentioned it. It has **not** the same meaning as in Logic.

Comment: I'm thinking a way to put this concept in logic. For two any true statements $p,q$ let $\lambda(p,q)$ the minimal number of steps to derive $q$ from $p$. Then we can say that $p$ is stronger than $q$ if $\lambda(p,q)<\lambda(q,p)$.